# How to upgrade web project with latest fancy Bootstrap & SASS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm developing a ASP .NET web project that uses: jQuery, jQuery UI, reset/normalize css stylesheets. Most of the CSS is crap, so I'm going to rewrite it + I will have a budget to it :)

I came across two fancy solutions that I would like to learn:

- [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)
- [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html)

I wonder, how to "mix" my existing application with these solution. When it comes to SASS, it seems to me pretty obvious - just rewrite CSS and be proud of new clean meta CSS, however I'm not sure about Bootstrap. What are the advantages of it if I don't want to change the layout of my site?

Another thing: can I run into possible issues when including Bootstrap / SASS into my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap (TBS) is a CSS framework and its original purpose was for website and web app prototypes. So if you want to start from scratch with very thorough and well styled CSS, then bootstrap is great.

Twitter Bootstrap is NOT necessarily the right solution if you want to keep the majority of your existing UI, especially if your existing UI doesn't match up well with their scaffolding,  grid system, and other elements of their UI styles (forms inputs, buttons, typography etc). You'll find yourself having to override a lot the framework's properties, which kind of defeats the purpose.

As @Nathron mentioned, if you try to mix TBS with your existing code, you could run into conflicts. Creating a customized build of TBS that includes only the elements of their framework that you want would be the best approach there: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html.

Regarding SASS, if you want to use it in combination with TBS, check out https://github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

From their site: The Boostrap JS is for "interactive components for things like tooltips, popovers, modals, and more". So if you are using any of those, make sure you don't have conflicting JS functions.

You could run into issues with the CSS if your class names are the same as the ones that Bootstrap uses. Many of them are a little obscure like "darkwell", but some of them are common like "dropdown", so you just have to keep an eye out for that.

Easiest way to see is to download it and play around with it :)